# Gradle call method inside a test configuration

Tags: methods, gradle

In my gradle build for to reuse code I declared a helper method that return a system property value passed by command line.
this method return a value of system property if set else it return default value.

I am able to call this method from other task configuration well. but when I am calling same method from gradle test configuration it is throwing below exception:

---

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':com.abilitynetwork.dps.iTest'.

> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
>
> ---
>
> Sample code is as below:

```
test {
    getProperty() //not working
}
String getProperty(){
   if  ( System.properties['test_prop']== null || System.properties['test_prop'].isEmpty()){
        return "file:///${rootDir}/com.abilitynetwork.dps.iTest/itest-application.properties";
   }
    return System.properties['test_prop'];  
}
```

Just wanted to understand about the configuration phase of gradle and why this method is not visible to test configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getProperty` has a special meaning in Groovy. Use a different name for your method.